# Find lat/long of points that are equidistant from each other if the start/end point is known in Google Sheets

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a shape like
[image]

I know the 4 corners of it.

I need to find the location of each of the points when I know the number of points and the fact that all of them on the X axis should be equidistant and those on the Y should be as well (the distance along X/Y maybe different).

If I knew the distance and bearing then the following gives me the lat/long of the next point

```
PointX2=(SIN(Radians(Bearing))*Distance)+PointX
PointY2=(COS(RADIANS(Bearing))*Distance)+PointY
```

So the questions are

1. How do I solve this for an unknown Distance if all other variables are known? Ex. I know point 1 and 4 and that the bearing is 90degrees.
2. Once I know the distance from 1 to 4 if I divide this by the number of points (6), is this the value I need to use to get T1b? Where 'a' is the first point along 1 to 4. Should I consider anything else?
3. Is the same true for working out the distance from T1 to T2?